# how to set forground and background colors in an html canvas element?

Tags: javascript, canvas

There are several posts that ask about setting a background color in a canvas element then drawing in a different color on that background.  I can not get this to work.

I have a fiddle [here (jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/sevenreeds/cra01fsw/12/)

The basic idea is:
HTML

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

jQuery based js:

```
$('<canvas>')
  .attr('id', 'theCanvas')
  .attr('width', 200)
  .attr('height', 100)
  .appendTo('#main');

const myCanvas = document.getElementById('theCanvas');
const ctx = myCanvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, myCanvas.innerWidth, myCanvas.innerHeight);

ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255,1)";
ctx.fillRect(20, 20, myCanvas.innerWidth - 20, myCanvas.innerHeight - 20);
```

some CSS to draw a border around the canvas:

```
#theCanvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

The end result is a black border around a white rectangle.  Whit I expect is black rectangle with an "inset" white rectangle that has 20px "border" around it.

What am I missing?

Comment: Typo: `HTMLCanvasElement` has no  `innerWidth` or `innerHeight` properties. `Window` does. `HTMLCanvasElement` has `width` and `height` properties. That's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

@Kaiido's answer is correct.  I needed to replace `innerHeight` & `innerWidth` with `height` & `width`.